# Json payload with a toString property

Tags: json.net

I keep getting a property set to null when I try to deserialize json which contains a toString name for a property

{
  "field": "status",
  "fieldtype": "jira",
  "from": "10000",
  "fromString": "Impeded",
  "to": "10006",
  "toString": "Review"
}

I tried with and without the following JsonProperty

```
public class ChangelogItem
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string fieldtype { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public string fromString { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "toString")]
    //public string newString { get; set; }

    public string toString { get; set; }
}
```

but I keep getting a null value.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine for me with Json.Net v6.0.3:

```
public class ChangelogItem
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string fieldtype { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public string fromString { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
    public string toString { get; set; }
}
```

Test program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""field"": ""status"",
            ""fieldtype"": ""jira"",
            ""from"": ""10000"",
            ""fromString"": ""Impeded"",
            ""to"": ""10006"",
            ""toString"": ""Review""
        }";

        ChangelogItem item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChangelogItem>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(item.toString);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Review
```

Comment: Thanks Brian I guess now that the problem is coming front NancyFx and my wrong assumption that it uses Json.net

Comment: I've not used NancyFx, but looking on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/NancyFx), it looks like you can use any number of serializers with it, including Json.Net.  Did you try loading the Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet package into your solution?

Comment: It works now, I found it yesterday evening too! Thanks for the help Brian